# Server.MapPath in ASP.NET Core Razor page

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET 4.8 MVC app which uses a static html header file in its layout file. This header file is not part of the MVC app but a separate web app called Header hosted on the same server.

```
 <body>

    @Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("/Header/Intro.html")))

    @RenderBody()

 </body>
```

Trying to upgrade this app to .net core. Server.MapPath is not available in .net core. Is it possible to use IHostingEnvironment in razor file?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create custom service, and inject `IWebHostEnvironment`.

   ```
   using System.Xml.Linq;

   namespace MVCore6.Middleware
   {
    public class CustomService
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

        public CustomService(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            _env = environment;
        }

        public string GetHtmlFilePath(string filename)
        {

            var filepath = _env.WebRootPath.ToString() + @"\"+filename;

            return filepath;
        }
    }
   }
   ```
2. Create `test.html` under wwwroot folder.

   [image]

   [image]
3. Register the custom service in `Program.cs`.

   [image]
4. My test code in `Index.cshtml` and the test result.

   ```
   @using MVCore6.Middleware
   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
   }
   @inject CustomService customservice;

   <div> 

   @Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(customservice.GetHtmlFilePath("test.html")))
   </div>
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Hi Jason. Thanks for your help. test.html is not part of the this project and so I would not be able to use webRootPath

Comment: @bluepiranha You mean the `Intro.html` file is out of the project, right ? I will test it later.

Comment: Yes. Its outside. Thank you.

Comment: @bluepiranha [It works in my side.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UE27xu)